# Given Force in vector form, how do I find work done?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work

A force of $F=\hat i+2\hat j-3\hat k$ is applied to a particle that moves 10 meters in the direction of $\hat i+\hat j$. How much work is done?

Comment: What about $W = \int \vec F \mathrm{d}\vec s$ or $W = \vec F \cdot \vec s$ for constant forces is unclear to you?

Comment: @ACuriousMind The vector part is confusing me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $W=\vec{F}\cdot\vec{s}$

*What components of $\vec{F}$ actually contribute to the work done?*

**Hint 2**: the dot product of two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ corresponds to the projection of one on the other, and is given by $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=u_xv_x+u_yv_y+u_zv_z$.

*Can you find the $x$-, $y$- and $z$-components of $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{s}$?*

**Hint 3**: in a basis $\{\vec{i},\vec{j},\vec{k}\}$ a vector $\vec{w}=(w_x,w_y,w_z)$ can be decomposed (by projecting it along each axis) as: $\vec{w}=w_x\vec{i}+w_y\vec{j}+w_z\vec{k}$.

---

## In steps, without actually giving the answer because this looks very much like a homework question and this isn't a homework-solving website:

**STEP 1**: recall the formula for the work $W$ done by a constant force $\vec{F}$ along a trajectory $\vec{s}$
$$W=\vec{F}\cdot\vec{s}$$

**STEP 2**: express the dot product in terms of the components of $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{s}$
$$W=(F_x\vec{i}+F_y\vec{j}+F_z\vec{k})\cdot(s_x\vec{i}+s_y\vec{j}+s_z\vec{k})$$
$$W=F_xs_x+F_ys_y+F_zs_z$$

**NOTE**: this comes from the fact that when you fully expand the product of the two brackets, for $\vec{a},\vec{b}=\vec{i},\vec{j}$ or $\vec{k}$, you get $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=|a|^2=1$ if $\vec{a}=\vec{b}$, and $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=0$ otherwise. Therefore, you collect the $x$-terms together, the $y$-terms together and so on.

**STEP 3**: compare $\vec{F}=F_x\vec{i}+F_y\vec{j}+F_z\vec{k}$ with the expression you're given, and similarly for $\vec{s}$.

**STEP 4**: compute $W$.

Comment: Can you continue on

Comment: I understand that too. I also know that whatever answer I get for F, I must multiply it by 10 in the end. But, I don't know how to get F.

Comment: @axasbit All good now?

Comment: No I'm still not clear

Comment: @axasbit I can't really go into more details without actually solving the problem - and this isn't a homework website.

Comment: @axasbit What exactly are you having difficulties with?

Comment: Well technically this isn't homework

Comment: I have a test on this tommorow, and the back of the book only has the answers

Comment: I know the answer to this, but I want to know how to solve it

Answer (score 2):

Hints :
$W=\overline F⋅\overline s $

&

$\overline s=|s|\hat s$

Answer (score 0):

The force is constant. No need for integration.

If you don't like vectors, try breaking down this problem into its three components. The work done can be seen as the sum of the work done along the x, y and z components :

*W* = *F<sub>x</sub>s<sub>x</sub> + F<sub>y</sub>s<sub>y</sub> + F<sub>z</sub>s<sub>z</sub>*

This should make it quite obvious.